# What is the function of a cursor adaptor in android?

Tags: android, cursor, adaptor

I believe a cursor is

•   An Interface which represents a two dimensional table of any database 
•   The cursor interface allows access to the result returned by the SQL database query

However what is the function of the Cursor Adapter in android?

Many Thanks, Josh

Answer (score 0):

A `CursorAdapter` is an implementation of the `ListAdapter` interface that wraps a `Cursor`. `ListAdapter` is used with collection-style widgets like `ListView`, `Spinner`, `GridView`, and others that inherit from `AdapterView`. The adapter serves as a bridge between your model data (the `Cursor`) and the visual representation as rows, cells, or whatever inside of the `AdapterView`.